# Why is it that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx $ diverges, while $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^8} dx $ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Why does $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx $$ diverge, while $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^8} dx $$ converges?

Comment: Just asking: Are you happy with the fact that $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x}$ diverges but $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{7}}$ converges?

Comment: yes, the first diverges, since the exponent is $>= -1$, the second is $< -1 $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, for $x\geq 1$, we have that
$$\frac{1}{2x} \leq \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
It follows that the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx$$
diverges, and so does the original integral. As for the second integral, note that
$$0 \leq \frac{x}{1+x^8} \leq \frac{1}{x^7}$$
and so
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^8} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{x}{1+x^8}dx + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{1+x^8}dx + \int_{1}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^8}dx$$
As we can see, the first and last terms converge by the comparison test, and the middle term is a proper integral of a continuous function and thus converges. So the whole integral converges.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that
$$\frac{x}{1+x^2} \sim \frac1x $$
when $x\to\infty$.

I assume (perhaps incorrectly) that you know that
$$\int_1^\infty \frac1x\,\mathrm d x$$
diverges.

Answer (score 0):

A primitive for $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ is given by $\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2)$, that is an unbounded function as $x\to\pm\infty$.
On the other hand $\frac{x}{1+x^8}$ is bounded by $1$ in absolute value over the interval $[-1,1]$, and by $\frac{1}{x^7}$ on the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$. It follows that $\frac{x}{1+x^2}\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but $\frac{x}{1+x^8}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and since it is an odd function its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ simply equals zero.